# Flask login "remember_me" does not work with Flask-WTF CSRF

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, flask-login

I've been scratching my head for the last couple days, trying to figure out an appropriate fix for this issue.

I'm using Flask-Login with Flask-WTF. Upon logging in, I am able to submit all POST requests to CSRF protected forms through Flask-WTF, and everything works as expected.

However, if "Remember_Me" has been set (thus placing a remember me cookie on the client side) and a close and restart my browser, on visiting the form two things happen:

1 - Flask Login captures from the remember me cookie, correctly logging
    in and authenticating.

2 -  Attempmting to POST any data, either Ajax or
    through a form, Flask-WTF fails CSRF validation, due to line 86 in
    Flask-WTF/csrf.py

```
if field_name not in session:
  raise ValidationError('The CSRF session token is missing.')
```

This is I'm guessing expected behaviour, as the session token doesn't theoretically exist for a remembered session, as Flask-Login pulls the user ID out of the remember_me cookie.

Anyone come across this issue at all? I have no idea how to go about sorting this - I don't want to disable CSRF protection, nor allowing remember_me tokens.

Is there some way I can refresh the session token on successful retrieval from the cookie?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30532781/flask-wtf-csrf-token-is-removed-from-session-before-i-can-post-my-form?rq=1

Comment: Unfortunately I tried that one - Didn't work in my case. I think this was affecting all POST requests in their problem, as they were running separate instances of backend and frontend and had to include creds for cross-domain.